# Dumping a Windows Mobile device image

Tags: windows-mobile

I currently have custom software programmed on Windows Mobile 6 devices which needs to be reverse engineered to remove the device restriction (currently the software is restricted to the programmed mobile device).

How would I go about dumping an exact copy of the device image and loading it onto another device? Are there any software packages that can help in creating a cab installer so we can program/reprogram it onto new devices?

The PDA device is a HTC P3470 running Windows Mobile 6.1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While this sure sounds a lot like a request to subvert a license, I'll bite.  Use a JTAG programmer.  You can suck the contents of flash from the device in raw format and rewrite it on the new device.  Of course if the software is locking itself to hardware by readins something outside of flash (like a MAC address, for example) then it's still going to lock you out on new hardware.

Theres a load you could glean on the process from www.XDA-Developers.com since they've been pulling and modifying WinMo images for years.

Answer (score 1):

Also if your program is written on .Net you can disassemble the program and recompile it.